# cannot read 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

i am trying to do unit test for a component in angular. i am new to the unit testing and i am currently facing the below issue

My component has select statement as follows:

```
this.store.select(getInfo)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.isLive)
    )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.text = data;

    });
```

My unit test case is written as follows:

```
fdescribe(‘TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>; 

  const testStore = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ['select']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent
        ],
      imports: [MaterialModule, FiltersModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: Store, useValue: testStore }],

      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })

      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {


    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

  });

  it('should create Test component', async() => {
    let initialState = {
         data: {
    “name: “xyz”,
    “age” : 20

    } , 
      info: [1]
    };

    testStore.select.and.returnValues(

       of(initialState.info)
     );
     fixture.detectChanges();
     await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should have at least 1 info’, async() => {
    let initialState = {
         data: {
    “name: “xyz”,
    “age” : 20

    } , 
      info: [1]
    };

    testStore.select.and.returnValues(

       of(initialState.info)
     );

    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    console.log("text is ",component.text);
    });

});
```

this is a very naive test. i am just trying to get the basic idea before proceeding to write more complex tests. 
So ,the issue here i am facing is . it prompts me an error saying:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined and this happens only for the ''should create Test component' testcase . the other testcase logs in the message as expected.

I am unable to understand where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a service each test gets a separate copy of the object provided.
You are setting the value of testStore.select to the original object inside of the test itself.
You have two options. 
The first is to set `testStore.select` right after you declare the Jasmine spy in your beforeEach.
The second option is to get a reference to your testStore in the test and assign to it.

```
const service = TestBed.get(Store) as Store;
service.select = jasmine.createSpy('select').and.returnValue(of(info));
```

Which option you choose is up to you. Since I'm not seeing a call to a component method I'm assuming that the component code you're showing is called from onInit. In that case the first option is easier to use.

If you want to change what `info` looks like for each test you can use option two and either call `component.onInit()` after you set what the select method will return or delay the first `fixture.detectChanges` to be after you set the select. This would mean removing `fixture.detectChanges` from your beforeEach.

More than likely you won't need async or `whenStable` for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the response.